# Regression analysis for change in overall score of a likert based survey

Tags: survey, likert, paired-comparisons

We have a pre-post study and we want to assess the effect of an intervention on the change in the scores of a survey in a group of subject.

The survey is made up of many likert questions.

We will perform a per-question analysis using an ordinal logistic regression.

But we want also to asses the overall change on all the questions. Averaging the likert scores between the questions doesn't seem correct to me because the likert scores are not really quantitative. But what other solution do I have?

Furthermore I suppose I should treat the analysis as a paired comparison, isn't it?

Comment: I'm not sure what an analysis of the overall change in scores would tell you. How many Likert items are there and how many subjects? Regardless, one approach could be to perform a principal components analysis on the Likert items, retain the first component and test for pre-post change.

Comment: 6 questions with 4 answers each. The head of the department wanted to keep it simple, so maybe using a PCA seems a bit an overshoot. Why you think that an overall change is not informative? it's an assessment of a general change. A colleague suggested to add one question which indicate the overall change, but I'm not so convinced.

Comment: Keep it simple, eh? Sounds like your dept head is innumerate. What about creating judgmentally driven factors or dimensions? Then by simply averaging the scores for each respondent for each dimension, you can test the pre-post change?